# How to add a ScrollViewer to the WPF application

Tags: wpf, scrollview

I have no idea about WPF application. I was assigned a bug to fix a simple issue to add a scrollbar when text exceeds visible area. For column 3 scrollbar is not visible. On the other side, there is scrollbar for the column 4.

How can I add a similar scrollbar to the marked column? It doesn't allow me to post all code, because it is exceeding the limit of 30000 characters.

Here is the source code.

```
        <Page x:Class="BinBrowser.Pages.Browser"
                      mc:Ignorable="d" 
                      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
                      Title="Introduction">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedContainerItems}}">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:TypeContainer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:RealProperty}">
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                                        <Binding Path="Value" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:BooleanProperty}">
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                                        <Binding Path="Value" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:DateTimeProperty}">
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                                        <Binding Path="Value" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ObjectProperty}">
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <mui:ModernButton Margin="5,0,10,0" EllipseDiameter="16" IconWidth="10" IconHeight="10" EllipseStrokeThickness="1"
                                                          IconData="{StaticResource Rightarrow}"
                                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Value}" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.Resources>
                </TreeView>

                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:DateTimeProperty}" />
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:BooleanProperty}" />
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:RealProperty}" />
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IntegerProperty}" />
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:StringProperty}" />
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ArrayProperty}" />
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ObjectProperty}">

                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Entry}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                        </Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="70" />
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Creator:" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData.Creator}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Created:" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData.Created}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Updator:" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData.Updator}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Updated:" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData.Updated}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Owner:" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData.Owner.Oid}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ListBox Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
                                    <ListBox.Resources>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:StringProperty}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">
                                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:">
                                                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IntegerProperty}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">
                                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:">
                                                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:RealProperty}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">
                                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:">
                                                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:BooleanProperty}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">
                                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:">
                                                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:DateTimeProperty}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">
                                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:">
                                                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type m:ObjectProperty}">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,4" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
                                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                                    <mui:ModernButton Margin="5,0,10,0" EllipseDiameter="16" IconWidth="10" IconHeight="10" EllipseStrokeThickness="1"
                                                                  IconData="{StaticResource Rightarrow}"
                                                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding Value}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.Resources>
                                </ListBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>


                <ListBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedHistoryItems}}">
                    <!--     <ScrollViewer Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="-133,-130,0,0" Height="100" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearchResults, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=boolToVisConverter}}">-->
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:HistoryLog}">
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                            <Binding Path="Type" />
                                            <Binding Path="Oid" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <mui:ModernButton Margin="5,0,10,0" EllipseDiameter="16" IconWidth="10" IconHeight="10" EllipseStrokeThickness="1"
                                                          IconData="{StaticResource Rightarrow}"
                                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateHistoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <!--        </ScrollViewer> -->
                </ListBox>


                <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                    <TextBox x:Name="searchValue" Width="100" TextChanged="searchValue_TextChanged" />
                    <mui:ModernButton Margin="5,0,10,0" EllipseDiameter="16" IconWidth="10" IconHeight="10" EllipseStrokeThickness="1"
                                                          IconData="{StaticResource Rightarrow}"
                                                          Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" 
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=searchValue, Path=Text}" />
                    <ScrollViewer Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="-133,-130,0,0" Height="100" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearchResults, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=boolToVisConverter}}">
                        <ListBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Entry}">
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Type" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Oid" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <mui:ModernButton Margin="5,0,10,0" EllipseDiameter="16" IconWidth="10" IconHeight="10" EllipseStrokeThickness="1"
                                                          IconData="{StaticResource Rightarrow}"
                                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Page>
```

Comment: I'm absolutely not going to try and find what should be fixed in this monstrosity of an XAML. The previous developers didn't know about separation of components? I'm sorry that you don't know much about WPF, but we're not here to do your job, but to fix concises issues. And if you're not able to find the issue yourself, you should talk about it to your employer.

Comment: Of course on the way of the work I will learn wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

if the problem is in column 3 it's probably in what I'm going to display below

```
<TextBlock MaxWidth="400" 
           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
```

here: (`<ListBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" .....`)

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedHistoryItems}}">
    <!--     <ScrollViewer Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="-133,-130,0,0" Height="100" Width="300" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearchResults, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=boolToVisConverter}}">-->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:HistoryLog}">
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock MaxWidth="400" 
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Type" />
                            <Binding Path="Oid" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
                <mui:ModernButton Margin="5,0,10,0" EllipseDiameter="16" IconWidth="10" IconHeight="10" EllipseStrokeThickness="1"
                                          IconData="{StaticResource Rightarrow}"
                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateHistoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <!--        </ScrollViewer> -->
</ListBox>
```

**explanation**:
for the `ScrollView` to be displayed, there must be a defined width and height, because it is not possible to have a `ScrollView` for an object of infinite size.

Comment: I will definitely try it out. Thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @masiboo decrease the `MaxWidth` of the `TextBlock`, try putting the `ScrollViewer` in the `WrapPanel`, make changes to see if it solves your problem.